# C# Double Click Button Event

Tags: c#

I have searched for an answer to this all day, but nothing has seemed to work. I have one button on the a windows form, and I want to Double click on the button to call up a messageBox. should be simple but I cant find the answer. There are Double Click events in other methods, but not the button method.

Comment: Can you use an image of a button instead of an actual button?

Comment: Don't do that. It is the most unintuitive thing in the world. People don't double click buttons in Windows. You will only confuse your users.

Comment: Why do you want to double a click a button? Maybe you should look for a different solution to your problem.

Comment: Bad design, most of the time it will fire two click events.  Even if somebody wants to help, you didn't give a platform tag.

Answer (score 4):

The Button control doesn't recognize double clicks.

You can derive from it and enable double clicks as follows:

```
public class DoubleClickButton : Button
{
    public DoubleClickButton()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardClick | ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, true);
    }
}
```

But as HighCore commented... it was hidden and disabled for a reason.  Buttons are not supposed to be double clicked.  But it's up to you what kind of user experience you want to create.

Comment: +1 for giving a reasonable solution. Regarding, "But it's up to you what kind of user experience you want to create" - A terrible one obviously.